# Strange invisible window causing 'dead zone' in Unity

Tags: unity, window

I have a very strange problem. Every so often a strange window will appear on the screen - well, I say "appear", but it can't be seen. I know it's there though. It creates a sort of 'dead zone' on the screen - always in the same place.

```
xwininfo: Window id: 0xe1ce72 (has no name)

Absolute upper-left X: 438
Absolute upper-left Y: 299
Relative upper-left X: 438
Relative upper-left Y: 299
Width: 502
Height: 222
Depth: 0
Visual: 0x21
Visual Class: TrueColor
Border width: 0
Class: InputOnly
Colormap: 0x0 (not installed)
Bit Gravity State: ForgetGravity
Window Gravity State: NorthWestGravity
Backing Store State: NotUseful
Save Under State: no
Map State: IsViewable
Override Redirect State: yes
Corners: +438+299 -426+299 -426-247 +438-247
-geometry 502x222+438+299
```

I can't identify what process has created it, and I can't get rid of it without logging out (xkill does nothing).

Any ideas for how I can find out what is opening the window? Has anyone else come across this happening?

Ubuntu 11.04

Linux laptop01 2.6.38-8-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:31:24 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

****Update:****

I am looking at the /usr/lib/unity/unity-panel-service process - I killed it, the process auto-restarted, and the window seems to have vanished. I will try it again next time it appears.

Answer (score 1):

Never had it myself, but I think that this is a [reasonably famous Natty bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/709461) :

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/06/help-compiz-rockstar-sam-spilsbury-squash-a-bug/

Perhaps you can help squash the bug, as per the article.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug [#755459](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/755459) and might be fixed soon.

To get rid if it I simple restart unity with Run Command (Alt+F2) and type `unity`

Answer (score 1):

For me, this problem is caused by the alt-tab switcher.  Disable the static application switcher in ccsm and use the ring switcher instead -- so far I haven't run across the invisible window again.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me as well, in my case I use ubuntu as guest OS in VirtualBox.
The reason was VBoxClient --draganddrop process, as described here: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14835
After I killed process dead zone disappeared.